# Getting RejectedExecutionException in com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

My Application getting crash due to RejectedExecutionException in GcmListenerService when receive push.

```
Process: com.myapp.app, PID: 22051
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.myapp.app.pushnotification.GCMIntentService@505ac0f with Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=com.myapp.app cmp=com.myapp.app/.pushnotification.GCMIntentService (has extras) }: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1@5792ce9 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@57d4d6e[Running, pool size = 9, active threads = 9, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 4]
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3048)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1455)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                                            Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1@5792ce9 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@57d4d6e[Running, pool size = 9, active threads = 9, queued tasks = 128, completed tasks = 4]
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2014)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:794)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1340)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzn(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3031)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1455) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
    03-09 19:33:19.171 22051-22099/com.eworkplaceapps.ed E/Flow: Inside initialize call
    03-09 19:33:19.226 22051-22099/com.eworkplaceapps.ed E/Flow: End of initialize method
```

**Thank-you in Advance.**

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273382/android-gcm-sometimes-app-crashes-because-com-google-android-gms-gcm-gcmlistener